# How to get axis ticks out of d3 without rendering in SVG?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm implementing a 2d chart using canvas. I want to reuse d3's logic for generating the chart's axes. d3 does quite a lot of good work in generating axes and I'd like to take advantage of it.

(Note: For backward-compatibility reasons I'm stuck using d3v3 for the time being.)

Consider the following d3 code:

```
let scale = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain([lo, hi]);
let axis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(scale)
    .ticks(num_ticks)
    .tickSize(10)
    .orient("bottom");
```

I can render this into a chart div with:

```
svg.selectAll('.x-axis').call(axis);
```

I want to be able to programmatically get the tick data out of `axis`, including the formatted labels, by writing a function that behaves as follows:

```
ticks = get_axis_ticks(axis)
```

`ticks` should hold each tick position (as a `Date` in this particular case) and the corresponding d3-generated label.

```
[[Date(...), "Wed 19"],
 [Date(...), "Fri 21"],
 [Date(...), "Apr 23"],
 [Date(...), "Tue 25"],
 ...]
```

I could then use this data to paint an axis on my canvas.

I've dug into d3v3 source (in particular here: https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/v3.5.17/src/svg/axis.js) but I find it very difficult to tease apart the logic from the SVG manipulation.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One idea I have is to use the scale function you have created to generate the ticks you desire and push them into an array.

As a very simple example, if you would like 10 ticks, each incrementing by a unit of 1, you could do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Q5Jag/3148/

```
//define dummy values
var lo = 1;
var hi = 10;
var width = 512
var scale = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain([lo, hi]);

//define your function
var get_x_axis = function() {
    let axisArr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    //calculate your value
    axisArr.push(scale(i))
  }
  return axisArr
}

//call it
let axisTicks = get_x_axis()

//log it
console.log(axisTicks)
```

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but if you need further help just ask.

Comment: Thanks Alex! I discovered that `scale.ticks(10)` essentially does what you're suggesting, but the returned positions are aligned on neat boundaries. E.g. if you're dealing with time, they're aligned on day boundaries, hour boundaries, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working. I found the time formatting strategy in the d3 docs: https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md#format_multi I believe this is the strategy that d3 itself uses by default when users do not provide a custom format.

I learned that simply calling `scale.ticks(N)` will return `N`ish ticks suitable for rendering on an axis. These tick values are chosen on natural boundaries. E.g., if you're working with a time axis, these ticks will be aligned on minute, hour, day boundaries.

Here's a solution:

```
let time_format = d3.time.format.multi([
  [".%L", d => d.getMilliseconds()],
  [":%S", d => d.getSeconds()],
  ["%I:%M", d => d.getMinutes()],
  ["%I %p", d => d.getHours()],
  ["%a %d", d => d.getDay() && d.getDate() !== 1],
  ["%b %d", d => d.getDate() !== 1],
  ["%B", d => d.getMonth()],
  ["%Y", () => true]
]);

let get_ticks = (width, lo, hi, num_ticks) => {
  let scale = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]).domain([lo, hi]);
  return scale.ticks(num_ticks).map(t => [t, time_format(t)]);
};
```